# best way to hold a file in a class

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I would like to hold a file in a class file.
I am writing an attachment user control.

After uploading a file by upload control, I would like to hold it in a class before I upload the file in SharePoint.

User can upload more than one file.

Only after that when user click on `save` button, I will save all files and other data, files to SharePoint and other data to Database.

Here is my class

```
public class Document :
    {
        public string documentName, documentPath, spServerURL, spDocumentLibraryURL;
        public DateTime lodegmentDate;
        public System.Web.HttpPostedFile postedFile;
    }
```

How should I handle it? Is it OK to use `httpPostedFile`? During my update, can I convert `SPFile` to `httpPostedFile`?

Comment: What do you mean by "hold a file"?

Comment: If you're planning on saving several files, you should use more than one instance of HttpPostedFile (or any other object that can hold files)

Comment: I don't think the `InputStream` will like being stored in Session, so read that stream into a `byte[]` that you store in that `Document` instead.

Comment: I will put Document in a collection. List<Document>.

Comment: @HansKesting - You mean I should has InputStream instead of HttpPostedFile?

Comment: @kevin - no, I meant that the HttpPostedFile has an InputStream property which probably will not store well in Session. So don't use that HttpPostedFile directly in your Document but read the file (from the stream) into a byte-array first and add *that* to your Document.

Comment: Should I put the document in Stream?

Comment: @kevin: no, do not store a stream in the session state. See my answer below for the recommended approach (we have this in production at hundreds of customer sites).

Answer (score 2):

The way that we handle this is when the file is uploaded, it is saved in a well-known directory with a temporary file name based on a GUID. The temporary file name and the original, uploaded file name, are then stored in a list of FileDetails within our class. Our class is then serialized to the page's ViewState, but it could also be stored in session state (I wouldn't recommend this in case your users open multiple pages or sign on to multiple computers with the same login).

When the save button is pressed, we loop through the list of FileDetails in our class, retrieve each one from the temporary directory, and send it to sharepoint (or wherever it needs to go).

We also bind the uploaded files to a grid so that the user can see the list of uploaded files and, if they want to remove one, they can check a box in the grid (deleted) that we check before processing the files.

Note that this process can also support automatic unzipping of zipped files: if you detect that the uploaded file is zipped, you can unzip each of the files to the temporary directory and add an entry for each one to list of files in the class. This could be a big time saver for your users.

Comment: Can I use Stream instead of HttpPostedFile?

Comment: You should not store Stream OR HttpPostedFile in a class that will be stored in session state. Just extract the file to disk in the web server and you will have a much easier time of it.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping documents in memory is not an efficient use of webserver ram.
Much better to store it in either a temporary database or fileshare...

However, I would not recommend writing this yourself if you can avoid it. 
Try looking at the [RadUpload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) control from Telerik, they even give you a 60-day trial.